# Serve playable but not downloadable audio file with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, security, audio-streaming

The scenario is as follows:

We need to provide some users of a web application with the ability of listening to some conversations that are recorded as mp3 files. But since those conversations are private, we want to trasmit them in a secure way (I understand this is done automatically if we use SSL), and we don´t want them to be able to download them.

Is there any way we can serve an audio file to a client so that it is possible to listen to the audio but it is not possible to download it?

I know this is not going to be very secure in the end, because anything you can listen on your computer you can record it anyway, but at least we want to make things a little bit more complicated by not allowing someone to download a bunch of conversations and copy them somewhere else. I am thinking for example in Spotify, where you can listen to some song but you cannot download it.

I am using ASP MVC as server, although I think this is more of a security question than something tied to specific technology. I have tried to return the audio file from the controller, but Chrome gives the user the option to download the file.

```
public ActionResult Stream(string mp3)
{
    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("someVeryPrivateAudioFile.mp3");
    return File(file, "audio/mpeg");
}
```

Can we stream it or transmit it in some way so the user can listen to it but not download it?
Is this even posible?

EDIT 1

Ok, now I have created a simple View with the following tag:

```
<audio controls="" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="https://MyServer/MyController/Stream" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I have tried serving a huge (around one gigabyte) mp3 file and the audio plays straight away (so I guess is buffering) and there is no option to download. So far so good.

Again, I know this is not secure and that it would be trivial for someone to workaround this and download the file anyways, but it is a start.

Now I would like to give the user the option to fast forward the audio. I have checked other questions on SO like [How to stream an MP3 from an ASP.NET MVC Controller Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643737/how-to-stream-an-mp3-from-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action) but I can´t find a way to deal with this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Listening is downloading. Without downloading, the user can’t play it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you server to user is downloadable.
Using SSL doesnt change anything, it just helps that some "man in the middle" between your server and user cannot sniff data. User browser will interpret web content same with or without SSL.

Even if it is represented as a audio stream, some browser plugins can download it very fast(like youtube video downloader).

Only way i see, how can you make your audio harder to download is that you create your own chunks of audio and play first chunk. Then create you own js which would prepare next chunk and start playing it after first one ends.  Then thirds, fourth etc. You can easily create it to work smoothly, but you are loosing capabilities of navigating in audio timestamps.

You can solve that too, but it also takes some smart code. Ot is lile reinventing the wheel of web stream :)